# How to use VBA to create subset and compute regression for each subset

Tags: r, excel, vba, subset, linear-regression

The data is like below:

[image]

I want to calculate coefficient of each group and fill coherent cells (column D&E)
I can do it in **R** with `subset()`, and calculate in each subset.

My **R** code is below:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(alpha.beta.d)){
    train.d <- subset(analysis.d, tic == alpha.beta.d$tic[row])
    if (nrow(train.d) == 0) {next}
    linear.regression <- lm(y ~ x, data = train.d)
    a <- linear.regression$coefficients[1]
    b <- linear.regression$coefficients[2]
    alpha.beta.d[row, "constant"] <- a
    alpha.beta.d[row, "coefficient"] <- b
}
```

But I can't find `subset()` or similar command in VBA.
I tried to use 2 for loop, but there are too many data.
How can I do so with VBA?
Or I don't need VBA, I can simply do the same thing in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand R so I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do, but Excel has a variety of functions for regression analysis.

The `SLOPE()` function will give you the slope *b* (which I think is what you mean by 'coefficient') and the `INTERCEPT()` function will give you the y-intercept *a* (which I think is what you mean by 'constant'). There is also the `LINEST()` function which can return a variety of statistics that might be useful to you (see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/linest-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d)

Any of these Excel functions entered directly onto the spreadsheet will return the values you may want without the use of VBA. However, below is VBA code to acquire the same statistics. It's not the most efficient way of managing data, but I'm not sure about your level of experience in Excel-VBA, so I've tried to keep the code simple to understand. You may need to play with the `LinEst` result depending on exactly what you need, and you can draw additional data by changing the last parameter to `True` (note that the return array would become two-dimensional so you'd need to change the constants given below):

```vb
Const COEFFICIENT_b As Long = 1
Const CONSTANT_a As Long = 2

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, r As Long
Dim groupFirstRow As Long, groupLastRow As Long
Dim colGrp As Long, colX As Long, colY As Long, colB As Long, colA As Long
Dim groupID As Long
Dim rngX As Range, rngY As Range
Dim result As Variant

'Define range parameters
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set this to your sheet object
firstRow = 2
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
colGrp = 1
colX = 2
colY = 3
colB = 4
colA = 5

'Set the group values to first item
groupID = ws.Cells(firstRow, colGrp).Value2
groupFirstRow = firstRow

For r = firstRow + 1 To lastRow

    'Check for a new group.
    If ws.Cells(r, colGrp).Value2 <> groupID Or r = lastRow Then
        'Set the row limit for this group.
        groupLastRow = IIf(r = lastRow, r, r - 1)

        'Set the X and Y data ranges.
        Set rngY = ws.Range(ws.Cells(groupFirstRow, colY), ws.Cells(groupLastRow, colY))
        Set rngX = ws.Range(ws.Cells(groupFirstRow, colX), ws.Cells(groupLastRow, colX))

        'Call the LinEst function.
        result = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(rngY, rngX, True, False)

        'Write the results to the sheet.
        ws.Cells(groupFirstRow, colB) = result(COEFFICIENT_b)
        ws.Cells(groupFirstRow, colA) = result(CONSTANT_a)

        'Reset the groupId and row variables
        groupID = ws.Cells(r, colGrp).Value2
        groupFirstRow = r
    End If

Next
```